# Facebook application not working

Tags: facebook

```
<?php
require_once('facebook.php');
`$facebook=new Facebook(array(
    'appId'=>'APP_ID',
'secret'=>'SECRET',
'cookie'=>true,
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();
if(!empty($session))
{
try{
$uid=$facebook->getUser();
$user=$facebook->api('/me');
}
catch(Exception $e){}

if(!empty($user))
{
    if($_GET[installed]=='1')
    {
        header("Location: http://apps.facebook.com/telebuytest");
    }
    echo "hi".$user['first_name'];
}
else
{
die("an error occured");
}

}
else
{
$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
echo "<a href='".$url."'>click here to add app";
}
?>
```

nothing works after $session = $facebook->getSession(); statement
but it seems there is nothing wrong in code

If i remove that code and put some html contents it works fine

Comment: The `getSession` method is way old, and does not exists in the current SDK any more. Read up in the docs on how to use the SDK, and see the included examples as well.

Comment: check http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/php-sdk-3-0-graph-api-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/

Comment: Yes getSession is old way. http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/07/21/updated-javascript-sdk-and-oauth-2-0-roadmap/  This helped :)